# List of submits in jQuery Mobile menu

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using a form with multiple submits to detect which button is clicked, but the list does not appear properly in a jQuery Mobile menu. I want it to appear nicely like in the [JQM docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html) (click the "Menu" button), but it instead appears like in [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/GNY2L0q.png). (In case it isn't obvious, the black boxes were me editing the names out.) What do I need to do to get it to collapse the submit buttons into a nice list like in the docs?

```
<a href="#navmenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button">Navigate to different section</a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="navmenu">
        <form name="navmenuform" action="X.php" method="post">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="divider">Navigate to:</li>
            <?php foreach ($array as $category) { ?>
            <li><input type="submit" name="nav<?php echo $category[0]; ?>" value="Section <?php echo $category[0] . ": " . $category[1]; ?>"></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is don't put submit buttons (at least visible) in listview items. 
The problem is that buttons and lisview item's content area have their styling `padding`, `margin`, `border`, etc. Instead of fighting with styling you can just leverage what jQM gives you.

IMHO the simplest way to achieve what you want, **if you can live with `GET` instead of `POST`**, is to ditch the form and populate list items with anchors that `href` to appropriate urls with parameters and use `rel="external"` like this:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="navmenu" style="min-width:210px;">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li data-role="divider">Navigate to:</li>
        <li><a rel="external" href="X.php?nav1=Section 1:1">Section 1:1</a></li>
        <li><a rel="external" href="X.php?nav2=Section 1:2">Section 1:2</a></li>
        <li><a rel="external" href="X.php?nav3=Section 1:3">Section 1:3</a></li>
        <li><a rel="external" href="X.php?nav4=Section 1:4">Section 1:4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to be able to `POST` your form you can utilize a hidden input and a bit of JS code.
Given that you'll produce the following markup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="navmenu" style="min-width:210px;">
    <form name="navmenuform" action="X.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="divider">Navigate to:</li>
            <li><a href="nav1">Section 1:1</a></li>
            <li><a href="nav2">Section 1:2</a></li>
            <li><a href="nav3">Section 1:3</a></li>
            <li><a href="nav4">Section 1:4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <input id="param" type="hidden" name="" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

Don't forget to put `data-ajax="false"` on your `form` tag, otherwise jQM by default will try to submit the form via ajax.

You then use `click` event on a list item, change name and value in your hidden input and submit the form:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    $("#navmenu ul li a").click(function(e){
        //Prevent default behavior since we need to submit the form instead of following the link
        e.preventDefault();
        //Change name and value attributes in out hidden input
        $("#param").attr("name", $(this).attr("href")).val($(this).text());
        //Submit the form
        $("form[name=navmenuform]").submit();
    });
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/Xt4vJ/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and your explanation makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!